# How to stop an IntegrationFlow when it parses all the files on SFTP server, and re-run it again next day with Scheduled function

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a `StandardIntegrationFlow` which reads some files from a bunch of folders on an SFTP server, filters and then process the ones that pass the filter. The structure of my files are like this: /home/{userId}/files/...

```
@Bean
  public StandardIntegrationFlow readingFilesAndProcess(
      SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory,
      PollerMetadata sftpStreamingPoller,
      RecursiveSftpRemoteFileTemplate recursiveReceiptsRemoteFileTemplate,
      FileeValidator fileValidator) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(recursiveReceiptsRemoteFileTemplate)
                .remoteDirectory("/home"),
            e -> e.poller(sftpStreamingPoller).autoStartup(false))
        .filter(Message.class, fileValidator::isFileValid)
        .handle(
            message -> {
              log.info("Handling message at: {}", LocalDateTime.now());
              handlingFile(message);
            })
        .get();
  }
```

I have created a recursive RemoteFileTemplate and I can successfully parse all the files for all the users.

```
@Bean
  public RecursiveSftpRemoteFileTemplate recursiveReceiptsRemoteFileTemplate(
      SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory,
      SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter) {
    final RecursiveSftpRemoteFileTemplate template =
        new RecursiveSftpRemoteFileTemplate(
            sessionFactory,
            1,
            file -> sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(file),
            List.of("files"));
    template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/home"));
    return template;
  }
```

To trigger the integration flow I am using this function:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *", zone = "ECT")
    public void triggeringFlow(){
        log.info("Triggering the IntegrationFlow");
        readingFilesAndProcess.start();
    }
```

My issue is that the first time that the readingFilesAndProcess flow is triggered parses all the files, but the second, third, ... time it doesn't do anything. (checked logs).

Is there a way to "stop" the flow when it parses all the files, so the next time that the flow will be triggered it will go through all the files again?

I am using spring-integration 5.5.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `@Scheduled` approach and you don't need to have your Inbound Channel Adapter to be stopped or restarted. There is just enough to have that `poller` to be configured for a respective cron expression to be run once a day.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work for me. When I try to configure the poller like this: `e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron("0 * * * * *"))` I can see that it only handles 1 file per minute. So, I suppose that if I had the cron expression inside the poller, then it will only process 1 file per day. 
My goal is to parse all the files, every day

Comment: See `maxMessagesPerPoll` and set it to `-1`. By default the Inbound Channel Adapter indeed produces one message per polling cycle.

Comment: Still doesn't work like this `e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron("0 * * * * *").maxMessagesPerPoll(-1))` . 

It parses all the files ones, but it doesn't parse them again. Expected to parse them again after 1 minute with this cron, but didn't do so for much longer time. Forget to mention that I am using an older version of spring-integration 5.5.15.

Comment: Do you mean to download already processed files again? There is a filter by default which prevents same files to be downloaded again. Not sure why would one wants to do that kind of logic. But see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/file/reading.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/inbound.html. So, if you really wants to process same files again on the next cycle, you might need to use an `AcceptAllFileListFilter` as a configuration for your `Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter`

Comment: Yes, my goal is to parse all the files and check the "modified" date. If the file is older than 10 days, I want to remove it from the server. That's why I want to read all the files again every 10 days, because a file that scanned today might not be old enough to be deleted, but it may be tomorrow. Is this approach completely wrong for this goal?

Comment: Well if you talk about just files removal, you might need to look into recently added `SftpLastModifiedFileListFilter`. This way you would never download files which are not old enough. Right, that filter is not available in `5.5.x`, but you simple can copy/paste its logic into your own class.

Comment: That seems to be the best solution for my problem. So to wrap up, I don't need any `Scheduled` function, I just have to set the poller to be triggered once each day with `maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)`  and use the SftpLastModifiedFileListFilter. Thanks a lot Artem!

Comment: Yes, that’s the plan